# ImageMagick convert SVG with text and external fonts to SVG with shapes (outlines) with no external fonts

Tags: svg, fonts, imagemagick

I'm looking to to use ImageMagick to convert an SVG file with text and external fonts to another svg without text, instead have them be shapes or outlines.

Basically, can ImageMagick do the equivalent of Illustrator's "Create Outlines" functions?

I can currently convert the svg to png and all the text and fonts render correctly, but I'm just looking to remove need for the person opening the svg to have the correct fonts installed on their computer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your installation of ImageMagick needs to be configured with the the "--with-autotrace" switch and [Autotrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) needs to be installed. Then a simple conversion command should work:

`convert text.png  vector.svg`

Comment: I think the OP is talking about converting text to paths, not tracing bitmaps.

Comment: Even though it adds a step, I think using ImageMagick to convert svg > png > svg will accomplish the same thing and has the advantage that the process can be automated.

Comment: Tracing of bitmaps introduces visual artifacts, so the results will not looks as good.  Also the OP did not indicate the need for the process to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt ImageMagick will do it.  What you need to do is load the SVG into an editor like Inkscape. Select the text and then convert it using Path->Object to Path.

Then you can save it and you can distribute it without worrying about the user not having the fonts.